# < Div> jumps down to new line

Tags: css, html, less

My yellow-div jumps down when text in it get a little long. [See imagesofproblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/254kP.png).

```
<html>
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; width:200px;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li><span style="margin-right:5px;">></span><div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow;">Hit me! Hit me! -Hit me! -</div> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

How can I make sure, that the yellow-div not jump down, when text get long. Log text should automatically get brokken to a new line.

(Is it possible to solve this problem without putting "width" to yellow div)

Comment: you can set your width to `auto` or just remove it, you don't want that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox to achieve your desired result (if that is an option).

```html
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; width:200px;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li style="display:flex;"><span style="margin-right:5px;">></span><div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow;">Hit me! Hit me! -Hit me! -</div> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Edit: Here's a version with your margins in place

```html
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; width:200px;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li style="display:flex;"><span style="margin-right:5px;">></span><div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow; margin:2px 0 20px;">Hit me! Hit me! -Hit me! -</div> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Tim Barnett,


Its works with style="display:flex;

But why ? What is "display flex" doing ?


Do you know if it works in every browser?


I accept your answer soon

Answer (score 2):

Try to change **display:inline-block** to **inline** like this:

```
<html>
  <div style="background-color:#00ff00; width:200px;">
     <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li><span style="margin-right:5px;">> <span style="display: inline; background-color:yellow;"> Hit me! Hit me! -Hit me! -</span> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```